# Different results between MySQL and PHP using the LIKE operator

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a search bar on my website to search for users name. When using mysql on my database the code works fine but when I use it on my website the results are not the same.

```
SELECT * FROM  `users` WHERE username LIKE  '%neva%'
```

This returns user named Nevada.

When I try it on my site like this.

```
$friendquery = "neva"

if(isset($_GET['friendquery']) && $_GET['friendquery'] != ""){
    $friendquery = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-zA-Z ]/", "", $_GET['friendquery']);
    $friendquery = htmlentities($friendquery);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%$friendquery%'";

    $query = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql);
    $u = $row["username"];
    echo $u;
```

Any help would be great  Thanks

Comment: Quick note: `htmlentities` is redundant here since you're already stripped all non-alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Best way to find out why = `var_dump($friendquery);exit;` before you run your query. Make sure `$friendquery` is what you expect it to be (you're overwriting the first line if the variable is not empty, and not running the query in that case - so the first line is essentially useless)

Comment: You should also use prepared statements. Don't rely in some sort of preg_replace to sanitize your data.

Comment: Could you explain what the difference is when you run your code? Do you get different results? Wrong results? None? Everything? An error message?

Comment: using the var_dump it returns string(4) "neva"

Comment: When using it on the site it only works with certain names. The user name Nevada for example doesn't work. But all the user names on mysql work fine.

Comment: Any help would be awesome. Could it be a Database setting?

Comment: This is weird. The username John works, Joey doesn't, Bigdog works, Nevada doesn't. Some usernames work others don't.  No clue. Need help

Comment: @user3399921 try doing a `dd($sql);` before `$query....` to see what query was built.

Comment: @scrowler using the var_dump it returns string(4) "neva"

Comment: @majimboo what is dd($sql);

Comment: @user3399921 dd is dump and die.